# PHP code for uploading multiple files

Tags: php, function

I have a function code with which you can send letters to the attached file. How to modify this code to send multiple files?

```
function xmail($from, $to, $subj, $text, $filename)
{
    $f = fopen($filename, "rb");
    $un = strtoupper(uniqid(time()));
    $head = "From: $from\n";
    $head .= "To: \n";
    $head .= "Subject: \n";
    $head .= "X-Mailer: PHPMail Tool\n";
    $head .= "Reply-To: $from\n";
    $head .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\n";
    $head .= "Content-Type:multipart/mixed;";
    $head .= "boundary=\"----------" . $un . "\"\n\n";
    $zag = "------------" . $un . "\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n$text\n\n";
    $zag .= "------------" . $un . "\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;";
    $zag .= "name=\"" . basename($filename) . "\"\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Disposition:attachment;";
    $zag .= "filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\"\n\n";
        $zag .= chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($f, filesize($filename)))) . "\n";

    return @mail("$to", "$subj", $zag, $head);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function xmail($from, $to, $subj, $text, $filename, $otherFile)
{
    $f = fopen($filename, "rb");
    $f2 = fopen($otherFile, "rb");
    $un = strtoupper(uniqid(time()));
    $head = "From: $from\n";
    $head .= "To: \n";
    $head .= "Subject: \n";
    $head .= "X-Mailer: PHPMail Tool\n";
    $head .= "Reply-To: $from\n";
    $head .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\n";
    $head .= "Content-Type:multipart/mixed;";
    $head .= "boundary=\"----------" . $un . "\"\n\n";
    $zag = "------------" . $un . "\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n$text\n\n";
    $zag .= "------------" . $un . "\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;";
    $zag .= "name=\"" . basename($filename) . "\"\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Disposition:attachment;";
    $zag .= "filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\"\n\n";
    $zag .= chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($f, filesize($filename)))) . "\n";
    $zag .= "------------" . $un . "\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;";
    $zag .= "name=\"" . basename($otherFile) . "\"\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Disposition:attachment;";
    $zag .= "filename=\"" . basename($otherFile) . "\"\n\n";
    $zag .= chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($f2, filesize($otherFile)))) . "\n";

    return @mail("$to", "$subj", $zag, $head);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do already have two attachments, so just add others by:

```
$zag .= "------------" . $un . "\n";
$zag .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;";
$zag .= "name=\"" . basename($otherFilename) . "\"\n";
$zag .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n";
$zag .= "Content-Disposition:attachment;";
$zag .= "filename=\"" . basename($otherFilename) . "\"\n\n";
$zag .= chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($otherFile, filesize($otherFilename)))) . "\n";
```

You could also use other encodings by setting other `Content-Transfer-Encoding`, all you got to do basically is to set the delimiter (`"------------"` in this case), to signal that a new file begins.

Comment: Thanks, I realized 
still need to add a couple of lines and eventually get someone may need